# Is there a mixed strategy in dominance solvable game?

Tags: nash-equilibrium

If a game is dominance solvable, is there a mixed strategy NE? If there is, how do I solve that?

[image: Game]

Comment: Hint: Suppose there exists a mixed strategy NE where player 1 randomizes between pure strategies $s_1$ and $s_1'$ with positive probability. Can you ascertain any dominance relation between $s_1$ and $s_1'$? If not, is the game with a mixed strategy NE dominance solvable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a dominance solvable game have a mixed strategy equilibrium?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/52092/can-a-dominance-solvable-game-have-a-mixed-strategy-equilibrium)